# Apt error code 112

Tags: 18.04, apt

I just reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 and I run the first command after installation which is `apt-get update` and then these error came out for no reason

```
root@localhost:/home/hafizat# apt-get update 
Reading package lists.. 
Done 
E: Method gave invalid 400 URI Failure message: Could no 
t switch saved set-user-ID 
E: Method http has died unexpectedly! 
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (112)   
root@localhost:/home/hafizat# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
root@localhost:/home/hafizat# grep -r ^deb /etc/apt --include="*.list"
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
root@localhost:/home/hafizat# apt update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method gave invalid 400 URI Failure message: Could not switch saved set-user-ID
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (112)
root@localhost:/home/hafizat#
```

and I didn't install the desktop environment yet

Comment: Is this Ubuntu Server 18.04 installation running inside a Docker container? 

Comment: No. This is a blank installation only with twm (xterm only) preinstalled

Comment: Please add the output of `id`, `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt --include="*.list"`, `apt update` to the question.

Comment: The output is now updated. So you may check it again